# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Email= '12' and Password '12''

Tags: c#, ms-access

it has connected to the database, but when I try to read from the database to validate login, I get this error.

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Email= '12' and Password 'fgrt''.
           at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
           at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
           at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
           at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
           at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
           at COSSA_E_Voting_System.LoggingIn.guna2Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\kusic\Desktop\COSSA E-Voting System\LoggingIn.cs:line 72
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
           at Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
           at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
           at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

This is the code when the button login is clicked

```
con.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    // cmd.Connection = con;
    string login = "SELECT * FROM tbl_students WHERE Email= '" + txtEmail.Text + "' and Password '" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(login, con);
    
    OleDbDataReader reader;
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    
    if (reader.Read() == true)
    {
                   
       MessageBox.Show("Email and Password is valid!");
    }
```

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***. also: ***never*** store passwords as plain text! ***hash them!*** please also read [when to add "urgent" to your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: can you help me out please? its a C# .net project

Comment: con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
           // cmd.Connection = con;
            string login = "SELECT * FROM tbl_students WHERE Email= '" + txtEmail.Text + "' and Password '" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(login, con);

            OleDbDataReader reader;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read() == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Email and Password is valid!");
            }

Comment: by the way, your error is here: `and Password '" + txtPassword.Text + "'"` - you are missing a `=`. which your ***error message*** is telling you: `Syntax error (missing operator)`...... welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: thank you @FranzGleichmann. i will try it out

Comment: it works, it is now reading from the database, thank you so much @FranzGleichmann

Comment: thank me by _actually reading the articles i've linked to_...

Comment: can you help me with the hashing too? I am actually trying to build a voting system as a semester project, can you help me out with it, please? and I will surely read the articles. it's my first time posting a question here.

Comment: there's lots and lots of information about this on the internet, and i'm afraid stackoverflow is _not_ a place to ask others to do research for you. but - when you want to hash passwords in c#, i recommend search terms like `c# hash passwords`

Comment: You are also missing `using` on your connection, command and reader objects. And if you just want to know if a row exists, you can use `SELECT 1 FROM...` and obviate the reader and just use `command.ExecuteScalar()`

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a bit size error. Try changing (force) your project from ANY cpu to x86, and re-build - see if that works.